# Spring Framework, enhancing Perfomance while dealing with data

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jpa, database-performance

**Application**

Spring-MVC application with hibernate4 integration, and spring security.
1 controller, two views, MySQL DB.

**Scenario**

a **User** entity, with some Lists that resemble relations between **User**, **roles**, and **userPosts**.

The application has a simple controller integrated with spring security.

After user is signed in, he can see his posts, or post new ones.

the Process of logging in would require a DB hit with retrieval of **roles** (Lazily fetched), as well as **Posts** (Lazily fetched), the data is filled up in the user Entity instance then passed immediately within the model through the controller.

**The problem is:**

In create new Post JSP (simple form) I am accessing a ModelAttribute (**loggedUser**) to get an instance of the currently logged user, as I think, no need to fetch the user again and establish all the repository sessions all over again. but sounds like there is no way to do so, as I noticed the stored user entity data(that I have stored after logging in) loses all the Lists inside the entity! while getting forwarded to the view. Meaning that any new request, would require a fill up of the ModelAttribute again.

**Things I tried:**

I tried enabling a class variable of User type and set it as operations happen on DB, to store the retrieved data then assign it within Model.addAttribute, but with no luck, as only those Lists (List User.userRoles, List User.userPosts ) kept becoming emptied!

I tried using a ModelAndView.addObject but again a new issue raised and it was related to assignment of Entity to string?!

I spent almost three days trying to analyse and figure out the mechanism these requests are handled
 but sounds like I must always keep hitting the DB as my entity's Lazily loaded Lists are always flushed!

**My Questions are:**

1 -Is there a way to keep the retrieved Entity data from the service/repository including the Lists while filling it up in the ModelAttribute/model.addAttribute? *(please note that I do not want to include a filter for cancelling the lazy fetching)*

2- Why is it that using sessionAttribute stores the Entity data successfully but loses those lazily loaded items? if we supposed that clearance of Lists happens as sessions got cleared when a new controller method was called.

3- Is there any suggested scenario to save performance, or minimize the hits made to fetch data from DB? am I missing some key design/logic good practices ?

Thank you for your time.

## UPDATE

Ok, Thank you **jmvivo**, and **M. Deinum** for your answers. I could solve the issue and now once the data has been gotten from the DB I am able to have it shared with no need to hit DB again at redirects/ new controller calls.

**The Solution:**

Using Map  model to store the logged user, and pass it to different pages.

**Observations and Notes:**

The objects created using entities, services, and repositories all resemble a data model that has to persist temporarily and get all the used resources cleared once the scope of the calling method has finished. this is why the User entity was getting some data parts cleared after it is forwarded to some other controller or other method.

In other words I just needed to create a user class, or some object to get a copy of the retrieved data by jpa, so that the dao object will have no effect on my read data after the DAO gets cleared.

This concept of separating DAO Layer and implementation Layer was missing, and I think through this little practise I understood it nicely away from theory for the first time ever.
Another observation was, As I can redirect to a jsp page I can also call the mapped controller method passing to it any results without the need to use Spring's dispatcher to do so (this is simply to save unnecessary processing of re-mapping):

```
@requestMapping("/home")
public String home(Map..){
// if authorised

//get user from map no need to call service to fill user based on principal name
SomeUserClass user = map.get("userfromDB") // user will be here :)
//.. some logic


return "home-page";
} 

@requestMapping("/post")
public String createUserPost(Map.. map, Model model, Principal p){

// access DB here and store result into map
SomeUserClass user = service.prepareAUserWithUserName(p.getName());

// save user copy in map, after the scope ends or another controller method happens the user will lose all lazily loaded data, but the map will be maintained by the chain.
map.put("userfromDB", user);


// if I want to redirect to home I can:

// call 1-home(Map)

// or   2- return the result of home function after setting model again 
// or simply return the page without the need for extra processing as result would be the same
// return "home-page"

//.. some logic
return "home-page";

}
```

This had great effect on my app's performance.
I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at [Spring cache abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)? This handles cache at service layer level. Example:

```
@Cacheable({ "books", "isbns" })
public Book findBook(ISBN isbn) {...}
```

> In the snippet above, the method findBook is associated with the cache named books. Each time the method is called, the cache is checked to see whether the invocation has been already executed and does not have to be repeated

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest removing the collection posts from the user. Not everything has to be a bi-directional relationship. The problem with all the bi-directional relationships is that your model can become too complex and hibernate starts generation large queries. Next to that you want to seperate certain things in your application (imagine that you would have a general security library how would you link the user to the post in that situation?).

After the removal you would have a service/dao method to retrieve the posts for a given user. Then in your controller you simply do a lookup and add it to the model.

```
public String showPosts(Model model) {
    String username = // Use Spring Security to get the username
    List<Posts> posts = postService.findPostsForUser(username);
    model.addObject("posts", posts);        
}
```

Or if you really want store it in the http session.

```
public String showPosts(HttpSession session) {
    String username = // Use Spring Security to get the username
    List<Posts> posts = postService.findPostsForUser(username);
    session.addAttribute("posts", posts);     
}
```

Next to this you could also use Springs Caching abstraction on the service to cache the results for a certain period.

```
public class MyPostService implements PostService {

     @Cacheable("posts")
     public List<Posts> postService(String username) { ... }

}
```

Key here is that you don't forget to invalidate the cache when the user modifies the posts/adds a new one etc.